# Issue with rounding number in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have problem with rounding number with 500. I am giving my example below and want to see how i can resolve this problem.

example:
Here i am calculating based on values from application:

{expectedResults} = 2242.31
{income} = 7166.67

${expectedResults}=    Evaluate    (${expectedResults} / ${income})*100
${expectedResults}=    Convert To Number    ${expectedResults}    2

my results would be like :31.29%

but if i get results like 30.0001 then i am getting my value as 30.0 instead of 30.00. I wanted to get the value as 30.00 but not able to find solution. Can any one give me the solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using evaluate - just use it a bit more.

```
${expectedResults}=  Evaluate  "%.2f" % ${expectedResults}
```

Full solution:

```
*** Testcases ***
Hello Computation
  ${expectedResults}=  Evaluate  (${expectedResults} / ${income})*100
  ${expectedResults}=  Convert To Number  ${expectedResults}  2
  ${expectedResults}=  Evaluate  "%.2f" % ${expectedResults}
  Log  ${expectedResults}
  Log to Console  ${expectedResults}

*** Variables ***
${expectedResults}  2242.31
${income}  7166.67
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am still not able to solve this problem. When i try to use above solution, i am getting FAIL : ImportError: Import by filename is not supported. ex:${expectedResults}= Evaluate  "%.2f" %(${expectedResults} / ${income})*100. Can i use this as below like:${expectedResults}=    Convert To Number    ${expectedResults}    %.2f.

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain a full example. I'm assuming your robot code contains some important differences that were not highlighted in the question

Comment: thank you.I will try this and see if i can solve this problem.

Comment: With this step Evaluate  "%.2f" % ${expectedResults} when the value is 0.365 then it is rounding down to 0.36 instead of 0.37, can anyone give apt solution to get 0.37 instead of 0.36 for example? Thanks